# OffSet + Limit query returning wrong results with adonis / node.js

Tags: node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I need to do this query using adonis:

```
SELECT * FROM book_unit where book_id = 1 ORDER BY unit desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

So, i do this function:

```
async procuraProximoSequence(bookId, offSet, maxRecords){
    console.log(offSet)
    console.log(maxRecords)
    const historicoQuery = BookUnit.query()
    .where('book_id', bookId)
    .orderBy(['unit', 'sequence'], 'asc')
    if(offSet !== null){
        historicoQuery.offset(offSet)
    }
    if(maximoRegistros !== null){
        historicoQuery.limit(maxRecords)
    }

    return await historicoQuery.paginate(1, 100)
}
```

This is the console.log() value of the offSet, maxRecords and the query that knex do:

```
2 <br>
1 <br>
  knex:query select count(*) as "total" from "book_unit" where "book_id" = ? limit ? offset ? undefined +8ms
 knex:bindings [ 1, 1, 2 ] undefined +111ms
```

If i print the result of the query i receive no rows:

```
VanillaSerializer {
  rows: [],
  pages: { total: 0, perPage: 100, page: 1, lastPage: 0 },
  isOne: false }
```

The expected row of the query is this image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like i can’t use `.limit()` with `.paginate()`

In my case, i do this correction:

```
async procuraProximoSequence(bookId, offSet, maximoRegistros){
    console.log(bookId, offSet, maximoRegistros)
    const historicoQuery = BookUnit.query()
    .where('book_id', bookId)
    .orderBy(['unit', 'sequence'], 'asc')
    if(offSet !== null){
        historicoQuery.offset(offSet)
    }
    if(maximoRegistros !== null){
        return await historicoQuery.limit(maximoRegistros).fetch()
    }

    return await historicoQuery.paginate(1, 100)
}
```

and now everything works